# How can you download all profile pictures for all users in a given SF org?

Tags: apex, rest-api

I would like to retrieve all the profile pictures of all the people in my org. How would I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have access to the REST API, then you can use the following python code:

```
import json
import requests

query = "SELECT+id,+FullPhotoUrl,+LastName+FROM+User"
query_url = 'https://na5.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/query/?q='
#access_token would be the access token retrieved from the OAuth process.
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}

#get list of all users (id, photo url, and last name)
r = requests.get(query_url + query, headers=headers)
if r.status_code != 200:
    print r.content
else:
    resp = json.loads(r.content)
    print resp.get('records')
    #for each user in the result set
    for user in resp.get('records'):
        photo_url = user.get('FullPhotoUrl')
        r = requests.get(photo_url, headers=headers)
        print r.status_code
        if r.status_code == 200:
            filename = '/jmm/pics/{}.jpg'.format(user.get('LastName'))
            chunk_size = 500
            #download the image and save it to your harddrive
            with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
                for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size):
                    fd.write(chunk)
        else:
            print 'head between your knees we\'re all gonna die!'
            print r.status_code
            print r.content
```

Comment: A few notes for Win users: 1) you will have to download python and add its root and root/Scripts directories to your PATH; (root/Script - to run "pip" in step #3.)  2) you may need to put all of the print statement parameters in the code above into parentheses - e.g. print(r.status_code).   3) you will need to install "requests" library by running "pip install requests" in CMD prompt, otherwise get a "not found" error.  4) create the "C:/jmm/pics" directory on your machine, or change the directory in the code.  5) to run the code, type in CMD prompt - "python yourFile.py".     Thanks, Edgar