# Move Chatter profile photos

Tags: user, data-migration

Users have been using a glorified sandbox for a long time now. It's time to ditch the sandbox and move everything to production.

We realized that users already uploaded profile photos in the sandbox and made things look homely! It'd be a shame to leave the profile photos behind during user migration.

How to move Chatter profile photos from a sandbox to production, during user migration?

Edit: Massive number of users (~1000).

Comment: Dataloader can often times be your best friend.

Comment: @crmprogdev, what would te the object to reference in dataloader, which would return an image?

Comment: @James. Depends on the API version. prior to API 34, it's in UserProfile > FullPhotoUrl. API 34 and later it's in User > FullPhotoUrl. See the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf) for more.

Comment: Okay, I took a look at the doc, but it only refers to photo URL, which is not the same as exporting the image, correct?   I may be missing something here :)

Comment: A photo *is* an image. The url refers to where the image is stored in your system. Some orgs may use a custom object to store their chatter profile images. Its no different than a record link.

Comment: @crmprogdev I think what he's saying is that field is just a string, a reference to an image hosted specific to the sandbox. OP wants to export the actual binary image file and repush. I was going to suggest Python and the API, but James beat me to it. +1

Comment: @BrianMansfield, thank you for clarifying and that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @BrianMansfield. What I was saying is that the reference will point to the location of the actual file so that it can indeed be exported. The string will contain the record id of the image file and presumably the path to where it's stored (depends on how the URL is formed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of searching, I found the answer at this post:

Exporting Photos: [How can you download all profile pictures for all users in a given SF org?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29798/how-can-you-download-all-profile-pictures-for-all-users-in-a-given-sf-org/29799)

It uses a combiniation of REST and Python, but should do the trick for you.

Importing Photos: [Chatter REST Api User Photo Example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5184/chatter-rest-api-user-photo-example)

**Alternatively**, if you have a small number of users (~100), then you may be better off manually loading them.